# Angular Easy Q - Getting data to update inside of my bootstrap modal when ng-repeat item is clicked

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This code is repeating my json data in li accurately, but when I open the modal all of my data is based off of the first indexed element, no matter which a tag in the ng-repeat is clicked. The problem may have something to do with making sure everything inside of the modal is data based off of its own ng-repeat li, but I cannot figure out how to do this. Perhaps a controller doing something like $parent.box but I am flummoxed.

```
<div>
<li class="boxes repeat-item" ng-repeat="box in boxes | filter:query | filter:filterCriteria | orderBy:orderProp | startFrom: currentPage * pageSize  | limitTo:pageSize | filter:filterExpr">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 work">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <img src="{{box.imageUrl}}"></a>
      <h4>{{box.name}}
        <p class="pull-right">{{box.completion}}</p>
      </h4>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">{{box.name}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <img src="{{box.imageUrl}}"><br>
      </div>
        <div class="details">
        Height: {{box.height}}<br>
        Type: {{box.type}} {{box.units}}<br>
        Opening: {{box.completion}}<br>
        {{box.snippet}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple elements with the id of `myModal`. Don't do that. You can create unique ids based off of some property of box. For example, `id="myModal{{box.name}}"` (if name is unqiue). Also be sure to set `data-target` with the same scheme.

Comment: Right on, feel free to click that check next to the answer :)